# Replacing text between single quotes

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to replace some text in an Excel formula using FlexCel, C# and Regex, but single quotes appear to be tricky from the googling I've done.
The string is like this;
`"=RIGHT(CELL(\"filename\",'C.Whittaker'!$A$1),LEN(CELL(\"filename\",'C.Whittaker'!$A$1))-FIND(\"]\",CELL(\"filename\",'C.Whittaker'!$A$1)))"`

I want to replace `C.Whittaker` with another name. It's always going to be First Initial . Last Name and it's always going to be inside single quotes.

I've got this regex matching; `(?:')[^\"]+(?:')`
I thought the `(?:')` means that regex matches it, but then ignores it for a replace, yet this doesn't seem to be the case. Suspect the issue is to do with how strings are handled, but it's a bit beyond me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?:...)` is a non-capturing group; it doesn't *capture* what it matches (that is, it doesn't make that part of the string available later by means of a backreference), but it does consume it.   What you're thinking of is lookarounds, which don't *consume* what they match.

```
(?<=')[^']+(?=')
```

But do you really need them?  You might find it simpler to consume the quotes and then add them to the replacement string.  In other words, replace `'[^']+'` with `'X.Newname'`.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the info. Was considering just adding quotes to the new name too. Have gone with that option.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to escape your character you want Regex to take it literally...

ie: `(?:')`
becomes `(?:\')`

Comment: Nope, regex.Match still pulls out the full `'C.Whittaker'` and regex.Replace still gets rid of the single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use regex? Regex is good for complex cases where speed is important, but it leads to difficult to maintain code.

Try this instead:

```
var formula2 =
    String.Join("'", formula
        .Split(new [] { '\'' })
        .Select((x, n) => n % 2 == 1 ? "new name here" : x));
```